# Any efficient way to loop database data to display in single row for same field?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach, row

I am working on a booth booking system. Customer can choose booth and the day to book.

[image]

Each selected check box will store in a booking ID after press button Reserve (etc: 3 checked box = 3 booking ID).

When I display all the booking, it will display all the booth and the day. If I book a same booth for 3 days, it will display separately in 3 rows.
[image]

How I want to modify my coding so that I can display same booth and its corresponding days in a single row as show below:
[image]

Here is my coding:

```
<?php 

     include("dbconfig.php");

     $query4 = "SELECT bookingID,eventinfo.eventTitle,boothAlias,testbook.bstatus,date,day, username FROM eventinfo, testbook WHERE username='$user' AND testbook.eventID = eventinfo.eventID order by date desc";
     //$query4="select * from testbook, eventinfo where username= '$user' and testbook.'$event'==eventinfo.'$event' order by eventID asc";

        $result4 = mysql_query($query4);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result4))
        {
        $booth=stripslashes($row["boothAlias"]);
        $day=stripslashes($row["day"]);
        $event= stripslashes($row["eventTitle"]);
        $date=stripslashes($row["date"]);
        $bstatus=stripslashes($row["bstatus"]);

    if ($bstatus==0){

        echo "<tr class='record'>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='80'>$booth</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='80'>$day</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='180'>$event</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='150'>$date</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='70'><img src='icon_stop.gif'/></td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='30'><a id='$row[bookingID]' style='color:#ff0000;' class='delbutton' href='#'><img src='icon_delete.gif' border='0'></a></td></tr>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr class='record'>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='80'>$booth</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='80'>$day</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='180'>$event</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='150'>$date</td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='70'><img src='icon.approve.gif'/></td>";
        echo "<td class='reg' width='30'><a id='$row[bookingID]' style='color:#ff0000;' class='delbutton' href='#'><img src='icon_delete.gif' border='0'></a></td></tr>";
    }

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs a `GROUP BY` clause, along with the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    bookingID,
    eventinfo.eventTitle,
    boothAlias,
    testbook.bstatus,
    date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(day SEPARATOR ', ') AS day, 
    username 
FROM eventinfo, testbook 
WHERE username='$user' 
    AND testbook.eventID = eventinfo.eventID 
GROUP BY booths, date
ORDER BY date desc
```

This is untested, but should do what you want. If you get an incorrect result, change what fields you use in your `GROUP BY` clause.

In your query, you're using an *implicit join*, which isn't as good as using an explicit join. Without knowing your table structure, I can't edit the query into an explicit join, but you should look this up and convert it yourself. It'll save you many a headache with larger queries.

Comment: I was about to answer this question using a sub-select but this is way more efficient!

Comment: @Tim `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` are really rather useful tools. To be used in moderation, however.